# Parental Control

Tags: parental-controls

I have young children who are discovering the wonderful world of the internet, but as it is known it is also dangerous. Some help they recommend to install firewall and parental controls, preferably open source. Thank you.

**Edit:**

On the pc I use windows and ubuntu, preferably ubuntu.

Comment: Please provide OS/release details of your system.

Comment: Ubuntu community help wiki - Parental Controls. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ParentalControls

Comment: @guiverc, preferably ubuntu